# generic parabola in polar coordinates

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections, polar-coordinates

Starting from the equation $y=ax^2+bx+c$ substituting I get the next equation in polar coordinates:
$$a\cos^2 \theta\ \rho^ 2 + (b \cos \theta - \sin \theta)\ \rho + c = 0$$
in case C was $0$ we could explicate ρ, so I made sure that c would result $0$, by find an auxiliary Cartesian plane of cordinate $(u, v)$ so that the equation of the parabola became $$v=au^2+bu$$
Now I can find the polar coordinates with respect to the new pole, $$( u=\rho_1\cos\theta_1 , v=\rho_1\sin\theta_1 )$$
So the equation of the parabola in this case becomes:
$$\rho_1\sin(\theta_1)=a(\rho_1\cos(\theta_1))^2+b\rho_1\cos(\theta_1)$$
explaining $\rho_1$ we get:
$$\rho_1=\frac{\sec\theta_1(\tan\theta_1-b)}{a}$$  $a\ne0$ $\theta\ne0$

To return to ρ we can use  the law of cosines
$$\rho=\sqrt{c^2+\rho_1^2-2c\rho_1\cos\alpha}$$
but $\alpha=90-\theta$
so
$$\rho=\sqrt{c^2+\rho_1^2-2c\rho_1\sin\theta}$$
definitely
$$\rho=\sqrt{c^2+(\frac{\sec\theta(\tan\theta-b)}{a})^2-\frac{2c\tan\theta(\tan\theta-b)}{a}}$$
Do you think it's correct?

Comment: Can anyone help me?

Comment: I haven't checked, but don't understand why you don't solve for $\rho$ the original quadratic equation.

Comment: @Aretino I have had this idea so I have wanted to try this way

Comment: The problem is you wrote $\theta$ for $\theta_1$ in your last expression, which is not correct because those angles are not equal. And converting $\theta_1$ to $\theta$ is not easy.

Comment: @Aretino thanks you, now I see the mistake.